# Anomaly detection on ALB metrics

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, anomaly-detection, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have a timeseries data of ALB and I want to apply anomaly prediction on it so that it will tell me ALB which is going to be faulty.
I have collected all cloudwatch metrics for ALB . Can anyone guide me how to proceed on it ?

Answer (score 0):

by time series data if you are referring to a AWS provided ALB metric or a custom metric that you are pushing then you can enable the Anomaly detection using the Console, AWS Command Line Interface, AWS SDKs, or AWS CloudFormation templates.

otherwise by time series data you mean anything else other than a metric then you can't use the anomaly detection.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-anomaly-detection/

"You can apply CloudWatch Anomaly Detection on any metric in your account, including custom and AWS vended metrics. CloudWatch Anomaly Detection will automatically determine a metric expected behavior, which you can optionally customize by specifying data exclusion periods, anomaly sensitivity, and the daylight-saving time zone. You can create alarms to notify you when anomalies occur. You can also visualize the expected behavior on a metric graph."

Comment: I am looking for Python solution with best machine learning algorithm which will be fit for this problem as we don’t want to implement cloudwatch based anomaly detection

Comment: @user12468166 follow this tutorial 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-built-in-amazon-sagemaker-random-cut-forest-algorithm-for-anomaly-detection/